# Nuxt-link on pan instead of click?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

The conventional `nuxt-link` navigates you across pages through clicking the link. I am wondering if I can trigger the same action of routing across pages through a pan instead of clicking the link!

Something that looks like this (I am using `hammerjs`):

```js
sliderManager.on("pan", function(e) {
    // trigger nuxt-link click and routes me to another page
})
```

The typical `nuxt-link`:

```html
<nuxt-link to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
```

Essentially, I'm looking to swipe to navigate to my about page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nuxt exposes the Vue Router instance as `$router`, so you could use [`$router.push()`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-push) to navigate to the link's [`to`](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to). Use [`ref`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref) on the `<nuxt-link>` to access the link from your callback.

```html
<template>
  <nuxt-link ref="myLink" to="/about">About</nuxt-link>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  async mounted() {
    await this.$nextTick()

    //...

    sliderManager.on("pan", () => {
      sliderManager.off("pan")

      this.$router.push("/about")

      // OR
      this.$router.push(this.$refs.myLink.to)
    })
  }
})
</script>
```

Comment: If you're using `ref`s in `mounted()`, you have to wait until [`$nextTick`](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick) for the `ref`. But I suppose it might not be needed in this case since the `ref` is used in a `pan` callback, which likely occurs well after mounting.

Comment: OMG completely amazing - I needed this so bad today and here was the solution...THANKS